# Overriding HashMap equals method in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

I noticed in the source code for HashMap it lists the equals method as final. Why is it that when I override it  I do not get a compile error?

```
public class Test extends HashMap<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Java HashMap equals method:

```
public final boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
        return false;
    Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)o;
    Object k1 = getKey();
    Object k2 = e.getKey();
    if (k1 == k2 || (k1 != null && k1.equals(k2))) {
        Object v1 = getValue();
        Object v2 = e.getValue();
        if (v1 == v2 || (v1 != null && v1.equals(v2)))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

That's the equals method for `HashMap.Entry`, not `HashMap` itself - look at how it's trying to use the reference passed into it as a `Map.Entry`.